# HTML5 canvas movable line

Tags: html, html5-canvas

I have a canvas where i put an image and, when it receives input coordinate, it draws an horizontal and a vertical line. The problem is that when new coordinate comes in, it does not remove the previous lines. So, do you know if it is possible ?

```
<canvas id="image" width="640" height="400" style="border: 1px gray solid; float: left; width:640px; height:400px"></canvas>
<script>
(function(scope) {
    scope.$watch('msg', function(msg) {
        const canvas = document.getElementById('image');
        const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        
        if (msg.topic === "coordinate") {
            context.beginPath();
            context.strokeStyle='red';
            context.lineWidth=1;
            
            // Draw vertical line
            context.moveTo(msg.payload.topX / 2, 0);
            context.lineTo(msg.payload.bottomX / 2, 400);
            
            // Draw horizontal line
            context.moveTo(0, msg.payload.leftY / 2);
            context.lineTo(640, msg.payload.rightY / 2);
            
            context.closePath();
            context.stroke();
        } else if (msg.topic === "base64Image" || msg.topic === "debug") {
            const image = atob(msg.payload);
            const imageData = context.createImageData(640, 400);
            let max = 0; let indexMax = 0; let idx = 0; let line = 0;
            for (let i = 0; i < 400; i++) {
                line = i * 640;
                for (let j = 0; j < 640; j++) {
                    idx = line + j;
                    const charCode = image[line * 4 + j * 2].codePointAt(0);    
                    if (charCode > max) {
                        max = charCode;
                        indexMax = idx;
                    }
                    imageData.data[idx * 4] = charCode;
                    imageData.data[idx * 4 + 1] = charCode;
                    imageData.data[idx * 4 + 2] = charCode;
                    imageData.data[idx * 4 + 3] = 255;
                }
                
            }
            context.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
            context.fillStyle = "red";
            context.fillRect(indexMax % 640 - 2, Math.floor(indexMax / 640) - 2, 5, 5);
            
            scope.send({ "payload": max });
        }
    });
})(scope);
</script>
```

Comment: The canvas is only a bitmap, It does not store information such as lines. The easiest way to update rendered content is to clear the canvas and render the updated content. If you are not keeping old content you may need to use a second canvas to hold that data

Comment: thanks. following your comment, i actually saved the canvas state with `const imageData =  canvas.getImageData()` and restore it with `canvas.putImageData(imageData)` before adding a new line.